# Intellij Idea - Find jar on web - failed to download

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I'm using Intellij Idea Ultimate 15.0.3 on Debian Jessie. I opened my old project, and when i'm trying to download jar from the web (by error in import statement), following error occurs:

```
Failed to download 'http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven/java3d/jars/j3d-core-utils-1.3.1.jar': Cannot download 'http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven/java3d/jars/j3d-core-utils-1.3.1.jar': http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven/java3d/jars/j3d-core-utils-1.3.1.jar, response: 404 Not Found
```

On my previous install (Linux Mint; Intellij Idea Community) all works perfectly.
How to fix this?

**UPD.**
Seems like problem is in dead link. But i have no idea how to change this.

Comment: There is no artifact at that location: http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven/java3d/jars/j3d-core-utils-1.3.1.jar you should update your pom to pull it from maven central

Comment: It's not certain from your question that you're using Maven.  If you're not, you should be.

Comment: I am not using maven, so i don't have pom.xml file

Comment: I get a 404 when requesting that URL. I guess it might have been removed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have maven or you can do following steps (Open Module Settings)

`Project Structure > Project Settings > Modules > Dependencies > +Library > From Maven...`

Then search for springframework and add it to your project.

[image: Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Modules --> Dependencies --> +Library --> From Maven...]

Comment: Very Low Quality Answer

Comment: Surely he should search for `java3d`, not `springframework`? I had to do similar on a project, but I was missing `javax.servlet`